# how to convert hash map to enum pojo having key and value in java

Tags: java, dictionary, enums

I have a hash map having values like this:
Map{Key:1,value:MALE,
Key:2,value:FEMALE,
Key:3, value:UNKNOWN,
key:4,value:OTHER
}

I want to convert this map into enum pojo file like this:

```
 public enum Gender {
   MALE(1), FEMALE(2), UNKNOWN(3), Other(4);
   private int val;

   Gender (int val)
   {
        this.val = val;
   }
   public int getVal(){
   return this.val;
   }

   }; 

   public Gender getValue(){
   return value;
   }

   public void setValue(Gender value){
   this.value = value;
    }
   public TestEnumPrac(Gender value)
   {
     this.value = value;

   }
```

I tried some ways, but didn't achieved what I am looking for.
Can anyone suggest how can this be achieved, what would be the best approach for resolving this.

Comment: `but didn't achieved what I am looking for`. And what you are looking for? Following is wrong `public TestEnumPrac(Gender value)` the constructor must have the name of the class itself (maybe a typo or a copy-n-paste error)

Comment: I want to convert hash map to specified enum format, yes it was a copy n paste error..

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close, but maybe overcomplicating or misunderstanding some concepts:

- There is wrong code `};`
- Duplicated methods (`getVal` and `getValue`)
- Misplaced and constructors `public TestEnumPrac(Gender value)`

**CORRECT ENUM**

```
public enum GENDER {
    MALE(1), FEMALE(2), UNKNOWN(3), OTHER(4);

    private int val;

    GENDER(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

}
```

**TEST:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (GENDER G : GENDER.values()) {
        System.out.println(G.name() + " = " + G.getVal());
        G.setVal(2 * G.getVal());
        System.out.println("MODIFIED" + G.name() + " = " + G.getVal());
    }
}
```

**RESULT:**

```
MALE = 1
MODIFIED MALE = 2
FEMALE = 2
MODIFIED FEMALE = 4
UNKNOWN = 3
MODIFIED UNKNOWN = 6
OTHER = 4
MODIFIED OTHER = 8
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct enum, but i need to convert the hash map in the enum format. I just want to know how can I convert hashmap to enum.

Comment: you mean at runtime?

Comment: yes, need to write a code which converts map into enum. I need to write a converter for converting hash map to enum format

Comment: pfff.... this can be achieved via reflection, but question is.... **why?** why don't use the `Map` directly? which needing you have to ask for this? seems totally unnecessary....

Comment: actually we are using a tool which requires enum for creating drop down list and we want to use  a file which returns maps in that tool. So have to convert map to enum for using the file in our tool..that's why looking for this conversion

Answer (score 0):

Taking Jordi's code as a starting point, add this method to map from integers to `GENDER` objects.

```
public static GENDER fromInt(int value) {
    for (gender GENDER : GENDER.values()) {
         if (gender.getVal() == value) {
             return gender;
         }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unmappable value (" + value + ")");
}
```

Note that a more efficient way to do this would be to create and populate a `HashMap<Integer, Gender>` and use that to do the mapping.  Or even just a simple array of `GENDER` objects.  However, these won't work if there is a `setVal` method that can change the `val` attribute of a `GENDER` object.

Hint: get rid of `setVal`.  It is unlikely to be useful, and likely to be dangerous.

Comment: Just have a query what are we passing as an argument in this method public static GENDER fromInt(int value) and also with this will i be able to create a enum with key and value

Comment: Actually have created a POJO that's why used getter and setters

Comment: A POJO does not have to have setters.  A POJO should only have setters **if there is a need for them**.  If there isn't a need, it is better to leave them out.  It makes your code easier to understand.

Comment: To answer your questions: 1) you are passing an `int` that is the same as one of the GENDER objects' `val` attribute.  2) Your question does not make sense.  The Enum >>is<< the map ... in effect.  There is only one such map.  That is inherent in what it means to be an `enum`.

Comment: I need to create a enum with hash map key and value. Like hashmap key and value will be enum key and value. With your code i think we are getting Gender value but I need to make a enum with key and value using hash map key and value

Comment: That does not making sense to me.  Perhaps you should update the question to show us how this *"enum with hash map key and value"* is supposed to be used.